# Why is destroying nested records happening on update_attributes and not on the parent save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes

I have two associated models:

```
class HelpRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :donation_items, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :donation_items, allow_destroy: true
```

and

```
class DonationItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :help_request
```

I have a validator that returns an error to the user if he/she tries to save a `help_request` with no `donation_items`.

```
validate :has_donation_items?
...
def has_donation_items?
  if !self.donation_items.present?
    errors.add :a_help_request, "must have at least one item."
  end
end
```

I'm updating both the `help_request` and the `donation_items` from within a nested form in which the user can destroy single or multiple `donation_items`. According to [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods), if the user destroys any `donation_items` they shouldn't get destroyed in the database until the parent is saved. But I've verified that in my case, they're being destroyed immediately upon running the `update_attributes` method. Here's stripped down code:

```
@help_request.update_attributes(help_request_params) # donation items get destroyed in the database right here
# do some stuff
if @help_request.save
  #do some other stuff if the save is successful
```

Here's the `help_request_params` with nested attributes:

```
def help_request_params
  params.require(:help_request).permit(:id, :name, :description, :event_flag, :due_on_event, :date, :time, :send_notification, :event_id, :invoked, donation_items_attributes: [:id, :name, :amount, :_destroy])
end
```

Is there a reason why the database seems to be getting updated on `update_attributes`?

Comment: Think I figured it out. `update_attributes` saves (or attempts to) immediately. Instead, I've switched to `assign_attributes`. Working out some other kinks, but it seems to have resolved the main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I figured it out. `update_attributes` saves (or attempts to) immediately. Instead, I've switched to `assign_attributes`. Working out some other kinks, but it seems to have resolved the main problem.

Comment: Argh, seen it too late. Good job figuring it out yourself :)